# Is (the) password password

Tags: articles, definite-article

Talking about a password for your computer, and confirming what it is.

1. Is password password?
2. Is the password password?

Which one is correct?

Comment: Stupid people shouldn't ask? Sorry to bother you that my english is too bad. It's better than when you were 4 though.

Comment: Are you confirming if the password is "password"?

Comment: Yes. Is #1 correct to use?

Comment: I don't recommend using #1. I believe the correct one is #2. Why? Because 'the' is used to indicate something specific. And based on your sentence, you want to know the specific password (which is "password") for the specific computer (which is "your computer"). So.... **Is the password 'password'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your sentences are understandable, but their effectiveness would depend on context.

> Is password "password"?

I can envision this happening as shorthand if I was intensely working on a problem with a colleague and we both already knew what each other was talking about or if I was muttering to myself, but I'd probably be more inclined to use

> Is the password, "password"?
>   Is "password" the password?

with a slight pause after the first "password" to differentiate the two "passwords". These alternatives would probably be used when referring to the login in the third person.

If you were speaking directly with the owner of the account, you would say

> Is your password, "password"?
>   Is "password" your password?

and more clear would be

> Is "password" the password that you are using?
>   Are you using "password" as the password for your account?
>   Did you use "password" as your login password?